# UIButton click event getting called multiple times inside custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which has an `UIButton` in it. When the button is clicked the click event is getting called multiple times. Here is the code what i am using.

*CustomCell.cs*

```
public static CustomCell Create ()
{
    return ( CustomCell ) Nib.Instantiate ( null , null ) [0];
}

internal void BindData()
{
    //some code

    btnSave.TouchUpInside+= (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("button clicked");
    };
}
```

*TableSource.cs*

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView,NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    CustomCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ( CustomCell.Key ) as CustomCell ??  CustomCell.Create ();
    cell.BindData ();
    return cell;
}
```

Any idea why is this happening? am i reusing the cells properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should not call cell.BindData() every time, only when you create a new cell.  Otherwise you will be running it every time you re-use your cell.

separate the bind data stuff... pull out the button touch

```
internal void BindData()
{
    //some code
}
```

and then put the button stuff in here.

```
var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CustomCell.Key) as CustomCell;

if (cell == null)
{
    cell = CustomCell.Create ()
    cell.btnSave.TouchUpInside+= (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("button clicked");
    };
}

cell.BindData ();
```

Comment: thank you for your response..i tried your suggestion..now button  click works fine but shows weird behaviour in RowSelected..

Comment: I would mark this as the answer and then create a new question about the weird behavior.

Comment: Hello Chethan Shetty, did you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Its late reply I came across same problem and solved as follow,might be useful for others:

```
cell.tnSave.TouchUpInside -= handler; 
cell.tnSave.TouchUpInside += handler;
```

This will prevent from adding same handler to button's touchupinsider event multiple time.  handler can be defined as :

```
void handler(Object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("button clicked");
        }
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work for me... for some reason...I will check anyhow