# custom tableviewcell button event firing multiple times

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitableview

I have a tableview which makes use of custom tableview cell.

When we click the button the event gets fired up multiple times but not all the times.

I have observed that cell is never null in below code in my tableview

```
var cell = (MyCustomCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell (MyCustomCell.Key);
```

I am using dynamic prototypes for my tableview

I think there is a problem with cell reusability and button even binding but I am not able to figure out why it happens and how to fix it ?

**Update**

```
 public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)  
 {
//Getting the value from arrary as data source here
var cell = (MyCustomCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell (MyCustomCell.Key);

if (cell == null) {
    cell = MyCustomCell.Create ();
}
button.TouchUpInside -= yourHandler; 
button.TouchUpInside += yourHandler;

//assigning the values to labels
return cell;
 }
```

Whatsoever it is I am removing the button event and adding it then it shouldn't fire the event multiple times

Comment: Post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, as well as a screen-shot of the  connections inspector for your table view cell with the button in question selected.

Comment: @DuncanC - Please find the update

Comment: I'm not sure how much I can help. I'm not at all familiar with Xamarin, or C#. Is "GetCell" the Xamarin equivalent of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? You need to post the code that "binds the event". Bear in mind that the DequeueReusableCell method only creates a new cell if no recycled cells are available. Once the table view is displayed, you usually get a recycled cell that your code already configured. (and if your cell configuration includes adding a target/action to the button then you may be adding an additional target/action each time a cell is recycled.

Comment: yes GetCell is equivalent of cellforRowAtIndexpath

Comment: in the above code cell is never null

Comment: can you post more code, or a demo?

Comment: It's absolutely disgusting, but I had this problem at one point and I ended up just disposing of the button in the 'reuse' event and reinitialising (= new() etc.) the button in the constructors for the cell.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt - so if you create the button again and add the event ... its not firing multiple times is it ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498047/uibutton-click-event-getting-called-multiple-times-inside-custom-uitableviewcell/40654749#40654749

Comment: @Sharath yep that's what worked for me. it's a bit wasteful, and there are times when you can genuinely get the -= += to work, but other times I don't think it does, personally I think it's a bit hit and miss.

Comment: Yes you are right !

Answer (score 0):

As cells are reused, your button event handler may be subscribed more than once for the same cell. An easy workaround is to unsubscribe before you subscribe:

```
button.TouchUpInside -= yourHandler;
button.TouchUpInside += yourHandler;
```

If you are using a lambda as a delegate, change it to a method delegate

Comment: It would be easier to help if you paste the whole code of the cell

Comment: You should asign the handler inside the cell code (i.e: AwakeFromNib). Never outside of it as you are doing now

Comment: My doubt is even if I am adding there at getcell ... I am removing the event and adding it again right .. so it should work no ?

Comment: It´s hard to say. Without the code (as I already asked for) we can only make useless guesses

Comment: Herewith I have attached my getcell code ... my doubt is If I am removing the existing one and adding the new one ... how come there can be more than one event handlers ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the events at **awakefromnib** in tableviewcell or else open up the storyboard in xcode and set up ibaction

```
    btn.TouchUpInside += yourHandler;
```

Iif u want to do something when cells are reused ..override **prepareforreuse** in tableviewcell

Comment: I tried on awakefromnib still multiple times getting called